# How can I make a special file filter for mercurial revert command?

Tags: mercurial

I need to revert all files in a working directory that match the name "test" anywhere inside the filename.

Is it possible to revert all this 3 files by using `hg revert -I` syntax:

- /includes/atest.txt
- /test.txt
- /test/test/test.txt

Answer (score 5):

It should work (I cannot test it right now) with the following syntax, according to [issue 1697](https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1697):

Windows:

```
hg revert "glob:*test.*"
# or
hg revert -I "*test.*" --all
```

Unix:

```
hg revert 'glob:*test.*'
hg revert -I '*test.*'
```

(Note the simple quotes for Unix)

As noted by [Blaise](https://stackoverflow.com/users/451480/blaise) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471956/how-can-i-make-a-special-file-filter-for-mercurial-revert-command/7472127#comment123131185_7472127)

> On macOS/Unix, you need to use `**` if you want to match files in any directory, e.g.

```
hg revert -I '**/*test.*'
```

Comment: @danip: considering a glob pattern is a "Shell-style glob", if it works for a shell, it should work as well in the Mercurial command.

Comment: On macOS (unix?), you need to use `**` if you want to match files in any directory, e.g. `hg revert -I '**/*test.*'`

Comment: @Blaise 10 years later, thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the given [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7471956/how-can-i-make-a-special-file-filter-for-mercurial-revert-command/7472127#7472127)

You can include all files in subdirectories in your revert by using the following syntax:

Windows:

```
hg revert "glob:**\*test.*"
```

And I assume Unix would be:

```
hg revert 'glob:**/*test.*'
```